# What is the benefit of wrting OpAmp parameters as function of G and Gfc?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, oscillator

This is a schematic for an oscillator. I am curious about how parameters are written as in the read box. I think G is the DC gain of the OpAmp. However, I am not sure what \$G_{fc}\$ is meant to be and why go we wrtite G as a function of \$G_{fc}\$ like that. What is the benefit of writing G = 10^(-\$G_{fc}\$ /20) instead of G = 10^(35/20)?

Also, because the OpAmp open-loop gain is not large enough (just 56V/V) can we assume the virtual ground here in calculating the voltage gain of invertering amplifier?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some **severe errors** in the red box.

Please note, that the open loop gain of the opamp is NOT given (in particular, it is not "56"). For all calculations, it is normal to assume an open loop gain that is large enough for allowing the use of simplified formulas for gain with feedback.

1.) At first, some **general remarks**: 
This a lowpass RC phase shift oscillator requiring a minimum absolute gain (inverting opamp amplifier) of "-29".
In this case, the oscillation condition (unity loop gain) can be fulfilled.
There is a small error due to loading of the RC network because of R4=Ri=100R3.

2.) From the given expressions - and in particular, from the form 10exp(-Gfc/20) - one can deduce that it was the intention of the author to specify the gain Gfc in dB terms. However, it is **wrong** to write "-35db" because this would be an absolute value much lower than unity.

3.) Assuming that the inverting gain is 35 dB the corresponding absolute gain value is 56 (must be inverting). This is by far too much and makes no sense (ideal gain "-29").
If no buffer is used in front of R4=Ri, a resistor ratio R5/R4=31...33 would be OK.

4.) The additional block X2(SUM2) is not necessary - neither in reality nor for simulation purposes. A kick-off pulse for starting the oscillation is always provided by the switch-on transient pulse of the power supply. During simulation, if the power supplies are always on (no switch-on at t=0) a small initial dc voltage at one of the capacitors (IC=1mV for example) is sufficient to start the oscillation process.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more question. How do you get the number -29 from the RC chain?

Comment: No - at the frequency wo where the RC chain phase is -180deg the corresponding damping factor of the chain is "1/29". Hence, we need a gain of -29 (at least) for unity loop gain.

Answer (score 1):

\$G_{fc}\$ is something like gain at the center frequency, or gain at the critical frequency, expressed in dB.

\$G\$ is the same gain, expressed as a voltage ratio (assuming equal input and load impedance).

It's not obvious why the other parameters are written in terms of G. Possibly it has to do with whatever your text is trying to teach.

> Also, because the OpAmp open-loop gain is not large enough (just 56V/V)

If that's the device's open-loop gain, it should not be called an op-amp.

Are you sure it isn't 56 V / mV or 56 V / uV?

Comment: I made a mistake in thinking that G is notation of open-loop gain. However, from the circuit, it seems that the open-loop gain is 10k V/V or 80 dB.